# Manage textview and switches inside tab fragments

Tags: java, android

So guys my question is simple, i'm migrating my app layout to android tabview.

I had all the code of the switches and textviews inside my activity_main.xml layout file.

Now i made 3 layout fragments resource xml files and i migrated everything there, plus i included the  layout app bar in the activity_amin file

I left all the java codes of the layout elements inside MainActivity.java without changing anything.

Now the app crashes becouse all the layout elements declared inside the fragment layout files return null.

Do i have to set the layout elemnts codes inside the frgament java associated files?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. You'll have to write those UI elements codes in their respective fragment class.

Comment: In that case how to that considering that FindbyViewId is not working inside fragments class?

Comment: In a Fragment you use [View.findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)), usually on the View which you inflated in `onCreateView()`

Comment: Thank you! It fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the Fragment.java-classes for addressing the gui-components of a fragment.
If you need a refresh for how to work with fragments you can read thru the codelab here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-fragments/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Best 
Sebi

Answer (score 0):

That's simple you probably working inside onCreateView of the fragment

try to work inside the onActivityCreate, because onCreateView the view is not ready and every thing will return null, so if you work on :

Kotlin:

```
override fun onActivityCreated
```

Java :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated
```

that dosen't happen.